# angular files can be viewed in production mode? directory src

Tags: angular, webpack, devtools

I did the deploy of the angular application, but in production mode, view devtools it is possible to see the original development files, is this correct? the application is in a docker container.

see the image

Image [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jNgaL8v-6Xqm9HbrhUbrpUcRy8EvsaVX/view)

this is correcly?

Comment: The image link you shared results in 403 error. Also, was the application built for production using the `--prod` flag ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of source maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32468255/what-is-the-purpose-of-source-maps)

Comment: I set the link image, yes i was using --prod flag